# Context free grammar for balanced parethesis

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I want to design a context free grammar for the following language:

> L = { w e {(, )}* | w is balanced}

I proposed the following grammar:

> S -> (S)S | E

Whereas the proposed solution in the lecture is:

> S -> (S) | SS | E

I am not able to figure out, what could be the problem with my solution.
I ran both the grammar for various cases such as:

> (()()), ()()(), and (())()

and both the CFG accepts these strings.

Can someone please help, what are the cases that my CFG would not cover. Or are they both equivalent. Or the number of transitions required to reach the final state are different.

Answer (score 4):

Both grammars generate the same language, so neither is incorrect.

I prefer yours because it is unambiguous, but that wasn't part of the requirements. Many people seem to find the other answer easier to understand, but that wasn't part off the requirements either, and it is a highly subjective criterion.

Answer (score 4):

rici is correct. To show the grammars are equivalent (that they generate the same language), you can show that one is capable of replicating the other, thereby generating the same strings.

For instance, the proposed grammar can generate `(S)S` and `E` as follows:

```
`S => SS => (S)S` and `S => E`.
```

Your grammar can replicate the other grammar as follows:

```
`S => (S)S => (S)`
`S => E`
```

For `S => SS`, you can't actually replicate that, or any other `S^n` which the grammar in the lecture can. That's OK, since you don't need to cover all of these, as long as strings of terminals are covered. For this one, note that `S^n` must eventually have all of its `S` changed into `(S)` (the other rule) and then work from the left:

```
`S => (S)S => (S)(S)S => ... => (S)^n S => (S)^n`
```

Now you are done.

You can also prove it by showing that (a) every string generated by your grammar is in `L`; (b) if a string is in `L` then your grammar generates it. You can do this by induction on, e.g., the number of pairs of parentheses.

Base case: For `n = 0`, the string is `E` and this in in `L`. The only string with `n = 0` is `E`, and it is generated by our grammar.

Inductive hypothesis: all strings with up to and including `k` pairs of parentheses generated by our grammar are in `L`, and all strings in `L` with up to and including `k` pairs of parentheses are generated by our grammar.

Inductive step: We show all strings with `k+1` pairs of parentheses generated by our grammar are in `L`, and that all strings in `L` with `k+1` pairs of parentheses are generated by our grammar.

1. Suppose string `w` with `k+1` pairs of parentheses was generated by our grammar using rule `S => (S)S`. Then `w = (x)y` where `x` and `y` are words in `L` with fewer than `k+1` pairs of parentheses. But then they are balanced by the induction hypothesis. `w` is therefore balanced since `x` is balanced, thus `(x)` is balanced and `(x)y = w` is too.
2. Suppose string `w` with `k+1` pairs of parentheses is in `L`. Then, by the definition of `L`, `w` is balanced. Balanced strings of parentheses must have the same number of left and right parentheses and must have at least as many left parentheses as right parentheses in any prefix (therefore they must also have at least as many right parentheses as left parentheses in any suffix). Choose the first left parenthesis and the first right parenthesis such that the prefix contains an equal number of left and right parentheses; this is a substring `(x)` of `w`. What comes after that substring must also have the same number of left parentheses as right parentheses and must have at least as many left parentheses as right in any prefix (this is to satisfy the condition that `w` is balanced); therefore, what comes after - let's call it `y` - must also be a balanced string of parentheses. As (proper) substrings, both `x` and `y` must be shorter than `w` (containing fewer pairs of parentheses) and they must both be balanced, and so both are in `L`. But them both are generated by the grammar, and the grammar generates `(x)y` since it contains the production `S => (S)S`.

QED